# Set memberships with no end date?

Tags: civimember

It would be convenient for us to have open-ended memberships. For example, our board members are permanent members of the organization (this is different from lifetime memberships).  I'd like to have their membership record maintain a start date but drop the end date.  Is there an easy way to make that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an additional membership type for Board members that is separate from your "normal" life membership. On the page where you create the membership type, you'll set the duration unit to be 1 lifetime. I'd suggest giving the membership a name such as "Board Member" to help distinguish them from your regular lifetime membership.

That gives you an open-ended membership. Here's a screenshot to show you what I mean:

[image]

Comment: Great suggestion - it does exactly what I wanted.  Thanks.